# Delayed change using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, cherrypy

I'm facing a strange behaviour in multi-process environment.

My first process (later called P1) writes to db through sqa. My second process (later called P2) reads from db through sqa. This second process is a web application which ask for an up to date data with an ajax call.

When P1 updates the data (write), P2 does not see the change (read) immedialty. It has to poll several times before actually seeing the db change `(issuing session.query(...))`. If I run another P3 process, I can see the change actually be done in db but P2 (web app) does not see it immediately.

I'm running sqa `0.8.4 (underlying db: sqlite)` on Ubuntu 13.04 and my web app is based on the `cherrypy framework (3.2.0)`

I used scoped sessions to get thread-safe session objects as mentioned in
[SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html?highlight=scoped_session#using-thread-local-scope-with-web-applications)

Here's my OrmManager class used by all my processes:

```
class OrmManager:

    def  __init__(self, database, metadata, echo=False):
        self.database = database

        engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + database,
                               echo=echo,
                               connect_args={'detect_types': sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES|
                                              sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES},
                               native_datetime=True,
                               poolclass=NullPool,
                               convert_unicode=True
                           )

    metadata.create_all(engine)

    # this factory is thread safe: a session object is returned (always the same) to the
    # caller. If called from another thread, the returned session object will be different
    session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False)
    self.session = scoped_session(session_factory)

def get_session(self):

    session = self.session()
    return session
```

P1, P2 and P3 implement an OrmManager and use the session returned as following:

```
orm_mgr = OrmManager(database=<path/to/my/.sqlite/file>, metadata=METADATA)

session = orm_mgr.get_session()

# do some stuff here

session.commit()
```

I checked P1 code. The db change is well commited `(call to session.commit())` but the change is not seen in real time by `P2 (web app)` compared to `P3 (cmd line process)`. It can take seconds for P2 to get the change...

Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot,

Pierre

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue.
According to SQLAlchemy documentation, a Session.remove() has to be called after each web request.

I added the following code to my cherrypy app:

```
def on_end_request():
    """As mentioned in SQLAlchemy documentation,
    scoped_session .remove() method has to be called
    at the end of each request"""

    Session.remove()
```

and:

```
cherrypy.config.update({'tools.dbsession_close.on' : True})

# As mentioned in SQLAlchemy documentation, call the .remove() method
# of the scoped_session object at the end of each request
cherrypy.tools.dbsession_close = cherrypy.Tool('on_end_request', on_end_request)
```

Works fine now.

HTH other people,

Pierre